# Javascript doesnt work in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

The following javascript doesnt work in IE9, but works fine in Firefox. Any idea how to solve this? Thx.

```
var element = e.srcElement || e.target;

if(element != null){
   if(element.tagName == "INPUT") {

   //alert("Before: " + element.getAttribute("type"));
   element.setAttribute("type", "password");
   //alert("After: " + element.getAttribute("type"));

  }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: See if `element.type = 'password'` works

Comment: The problem is the IE does not like changing the `type` attribute dynamically. Some solutions I've found are to replace the element with a newly created one with the same specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I've found that a plausible solution is to replace the element with a new one, you could use something like this:

```
var input = element;
var input2 = input.cloneNode(false);
input2.type = "password";
input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2, input);
```

Found here http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/705445-dynamically-change-input-type-text-password and modified slightly. Another solution off there is to use `createElement` instead of cloning, but that might take some more work.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the problem seems to be that IE does not like changing the `type` attribute of an element dynamically after it has been included in the DOM.

Comment: +1, but IE's problem is if the element is (or was) in a form. It's OK with changing type otherwise.

Comment: @RobG Hmm, really? Hadn't even bothered checking. For the few things I read, all people said was just the general "IE doesn't like changing its type dynamically". Good to know then. Do you have any links for this new form information? Just wanting to read about it. I'm sure I could find more if I looked more

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few notes:

```
 // ------------v---favor e.target
var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

// -----v---simple truthy test
if (element){
  // ------------v---------v---- use nodeName, and toUpperCase() for safety
    if (element.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT") {

           // Not all IE respects the changing of the "type" on an input
        element.setAttribute("type", "password");

    } 
}
```

I think the `tagName` representation may have changed in IE9. Using `nodeName` *should* guarantee upper case characters, but there are a couple rare bugs to avoid, so we use `toUpperCase()`.

In the past, IE has not allowed a change of the `"type"` of an `input` element. Not sire if that's still the case in IE9, but certainly IE8 and lower won't allow this.

Comment: (off topic, and without researching at all) Would you say using `nodeName` is the safe way to go, for legacy support and for moving forward, to get the "tag name"?

Comment: @Ian:  `nodeName` gives the upper case tag name, plus it gives representations for different types of nodes, so it's generally considered a good choice to standardize on it. However there are a couple of IE bugs in a couple narrow cases, so the `.toUpperCase()` is advised.

Comment: Right, I would always use `toUpperCase` (or `toLowerCase`) when needing to compare to a string. But I guess I really meant - has `nodeName` always been supported? I guess as I look at MDN, it seems to be fully supported, so that was probably a silly concern. And I also see what you mean by what is returned for different types of nodes. Good to know. Not that I use this very often (or ever), but something I will remember to stick with.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, it has very good support. Just a couple IE 5.5 bugs. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t20 FWIW, quirksmode advises its use over [`tagName`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t23)

Comment: BUGS IN IE 5.5? I CAN'T USE `nodeName` THEN. :)

Comment: BTW, [`nodeName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095) is a generic DOM method, it **does not** guarantee the tag name is returned in upper case. It's supposed to work with XML also, where tag names are case sensitive and automatic conversion to upper or lower case would be a bad thing. If working with HTML documents, [`tagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-104682815) is more widely implemented. Conversion to upper or lower case should still be done to "normalise" the name as not all UAs follow the spec and tagname case is irrelevant in HTML.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for that info. Definitely always normalize the case, no matter what method. So why do you say `tagName` is more widely implemented? Honestly just wondering, I'd like to know any facts

Comment: @RobG: I was speaking within the context of HTML documents where upper case is required.

Comment: @Ian—There are older versions of IE that don't implement nodeName. There are a vast number of browsers now on TVs, phones, game consoles, fridges, etc. that are based on IE and often old, crappy versions. All else being equal, I think it's best to go with whatever is most widely and longest supported.